# Database object was released by the GC without being closed first

Tags: java, garbage-collection, codenameone

I have a strange problem here showing me that some Database Object was released altough in the method shown below is no Database connection at least.

Console Output:

```
SOMETIMES I DROP GC stuff
WITH FILENAME stuff
WITH FILENAME stuff
WITH FILENAME stuff
**** WARNING! Database object was released by the GC without being closed first! This might cause crashes on iOS *****
**** WARNING! Database object was released by the GC without being closed first! This might cause crashes on iOS *****
**** WARNING! Database object was released by the GC without being closed first! This might cause crashes on iOS *****
WITH FILENAME stuff
WITH FILENAME stuff
WITH FILENAME stuff
AND GC stuff is somewhere here
```

and the corresponding method

```
@Override
    protected boolean initListModelPhotoList(List cmp) {
        Integer imgHeight = Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight() / 10;
        Image placeholderImg = fetchResourceFile().getImage("camera_placeholder.png");

        System.err.println("SOMETIMES I DROP GC stuff");
        Storage storage = Storage.getInstance();

        Vector vector = new Vector();
        for (xyz.model.Image image : images) {
            if (!image.getDeleted()) {
                Hashtable tableItem = new Hashtable();
                Image img = null;
                try {
                    if (!storage.exists(image.getFileName())) {
                        img = placeholderImg;
                        tableItem.put("icon", img.scaled(imgHeight, -1));
                    } else {
                        InputStream is = storage.createInputStream(image.getFileName());
                        img = Image.createImage(is);
                        // tableItem.put("icon", img.scaled(imgHeight, -1));
                        is.close();
                        System.err.println("WITH FILENAME stuff");
                    }
                    tableItem.put("emblem", image.getFileName());
                    tableItem.put("sort", image.getSort());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                vector.add(tableItem);
            }
        }
        System.err.println("AND GC stuff is somewhere here");
        cmp.setModel(new com.codename1.ui.list.DefaultListModel(vector));
        return true;
    }
```

I even tried to do a close() and Util.cleanup(is) on the InputStream to check what the problem is here. Normally my implementation was Storage.getInstance() for each call in this Method.

When i comment the line after `Inputstream is` in the else part, i dont get such a Message in the Console

So the question im asking here is if there is a misuse of the methods or if i can ignore this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That warning means that you didn't close a cursor in the database and just let the GC collect it for you. It has nothing to do with the code you posted and is related to code that uses the database/SQL package.

This warning is there to protect you from iOS where code **MUST** properly close connections because iOS's version of sqlite is **REALLY** sensitive to thread access and will crash if accessed by two threads. The GC finalizer executes in a separate thread, so relying on finalization of these objects can crash your app.

Comment: i refactored my DAO methods a while ago to optimize and fix code, but after your message i really could find a method which was not closed correctly, afterwards the error was still present altough it only came once. Now digging a bit deeper i could improve the code again a bit and i think its gone now.

EDIT: The error was lying in a method which called a DAO, and looping through the objects returned from, here another DAO was opened and called the child objects. Thats why i overseen and forgot to close (y). The Error was also in the method called before `initList` call